# Restarting Hudson - Windows Installation

Tags: windows-server-2003, hudson, continuous-integration

Whenever I update/install a new plugin or update hudson. Once the new plugin/update has been installed a button appears "Restart when no jobs are running."

If I click this button hudson appears to try to restart but then just hangs. Has anyone else experienced this? Can hudson be forced to restart another way?

I've tried restarting the service but this has no effect.

I've asked this question over at stack overflow, so will update this if I get an answer from there.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Some more info on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759709/restarting-hudson-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Hudson are you using? This seems to be a known bug in certain versions of Hudson:

https://hudson.dev.java.net/changelog.html (Fixed in v1.380)